# Images not rendered on certain devices

Tags: react-native

[image]

In this image , you see navigation button in top left rendered with image,
but when i try to load on certain one specific device it the image is not rendered but i can able to click the button and any images are not rendered any where in the app

enviroiment

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.8" 
 Nokia 7 plus
build number :00WW_3_51F_SP02
android  version :9
```

Comment: I was getting error on nokia phone for ssl issue

Comment: ssl does't seems to related to my project , could u please more elobrative>

Comment: the backend i was using didn't had an ssl, so after using ssl i was able to use my apis in the app

Comment: so what could be the solution